# iOS – How to allow a label to be pushed to the left by a label that needs more space?

Tags: ios, constraints, tableview, cell

This is a cell layout as built in the storyboard editor:

[image: Cell layout]

The actual result running on a device is this:

[image: Result]

What would be the best way to prevent the label with the gray background from being cut off by the blue label? A high compression resistance priority doesn't work. The gray label needs to be able to expand to the left and push the blue label back.

Comment: did you try suggested constraints?

Comment: Oh, one more thing. These are self-sizing cells? That means that it is not enough to have the image view constrain its height and width and top and left. You also need a constraint _to the bottom_ - because that is what will size the cell. So, as I say, let's just get that part right before we go any further.

Comment: @matt I tried moving the distance label to a different location, this is actually where it was originally but I moved it in order to fix issues that came up in iOS 8. Do you happen to know a solution to the updated question?

Comment: See the example from my book here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch01p038constraintsInequalitiesAndPriorities/ch14p393constraintsInequalitiesAndPriorities/ViewController.swift It might give you some ideas